# How to fix the error: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found

Tags: actionscript-3

I use the code and I get an error

> msg: Error #2044: Unhandled
>   IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL
>   Not Found.

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(myLoader);
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("gallery/test.swf");
myLoader.load(url);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Add code formatting to your code. Just add 4 spaces to the beginning of a line to make it code formatted.

Comment: Is this error happening locally while testing in the debugger ? Also, is the .swf that this code is in, loaded by another .swf or into an html page? Also, check the case of the url path listed there, to ensure it matches EXACTLY.

Answer (score 6):

Gotta add the listeners

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    context.checkPolicyFile = true; 

var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("gallery/test.swf");

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
    myLoader.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, errorHandlerAsyncErrorEvent);
    myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandlerIOErrorEvent);
    myLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandlerSecurityErrorEvent);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, infoIOErrorEvent);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressListener);

    myLoader.load( url,context );
    myLoader.load( url);



function progressListener (e:ProgressEvent):void{
   trace("Downloaded " + e.bytesLoaded + " out of " + e.bytesTotal + " bytes");
}
function initHandler( e:Event ):void{
  trace( 'load init' );
}
function errorHandlerErrorEvent( e:ErrorEvent ):void{
  trace( 'errorHandlerErrorEvent ' + e.toString() );
}
function infoIOErrorEvent( e:IOErrorEvent ):void{
  trace( 'infoIOErrorEvent ' + e.toString() );
}
function errorHandlerIOErrorEvent( e:IOErrorEvent ):void{
  trace( 'errorHandlerIOErrorEvent ' + e.toString() );
}
function errorHandlerAsyncErrorEvent( e:AsyncErrorEvent ) :void{
  trace( 'errorHandlerAsyncErrorEvent ' + e.toString() );
}
function errorHandlerSecurityErrorEvent( e:SecurityErrorEvent ):void{
  trace( 'errorHandlerSecurityErrorEvent ' + e.toString(
                                                        ) );
}
function onLoadComplete( e:Event ):void{
  trace( 'onLoadComplete' );
}
```

Comment: I tried your code then I got this error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at test_fla::GRIDGALLERY_1/frame1()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at test_fla::GRIDGALLERY_1/set_normalscreen_xy()
 at test_fla::GRIDGALLERY_1/create_gallery()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: what object is the null object? what line? I will make a working copy and test it

Comment: Code works fine for me. All I did was copy and paste the code into a new FLA and changed the url to the download file. I also added trace statements for you in my code

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that the directory gallery/ exists relative to your .swf (not your .fla), and that the swf "test.swf" is inside that folder, so that it can be loaded. Check your publish settings (shift+f12) to make sure your swf is publishing where you expect it to be.